# Calculus of constructions: Why forall when pi exists?

Tags: dependent-type, type-systems, calculus-of-constructions

I'm studying the calculus of constructions from ATAPL, Chapter 2. I'm trying to understand the *Type Equivalence* rule, which describes the meaning of the new type family `Prf a`. The rule states:

```
Γ ⊢ T :: *         Γ, x:T ⊢ t: Prop
---------------------------------------[QT-ALL]
Γ ⊢ Prf (all x:T.t) ≡ Πx:T. Prf t :: *
```

This rule seems to state that types of the form of `Prf(all ...)` is *equivalent* to `Π` types. Combining this with the information that:

1. `Prf: Πx:Prop.*` [`Prof` needs `Prop` as input]
2. The only constructor of `Prop` is of the form `all ...`

implies that the *only* well-typed occurrence of `Prf` we can have is of the form `Prf (all ...)`, which is equivalent to the Pi-type encoding (as given by `QT-ALL`).
Thus, I see no benefit gained by adding the `Prf/Prop` mechanism. I believe we gain something to do with impredicativity, as we can use `all x:T.t : Prop` to quantify over `Prop` itself. I don't know enough theory to judge whether this is possible or impossible just using `Pi` types.

Clearly, I am missing something. Could I please have an explanation of what we gain by introducing `Prf/Prop` that we did not already have with `Pi` types?

I've added a picture of the full definition here:

[image]

Comment: Isn't `Prf` just the decoding of the element of `Prop` to types? That is, the elements of `Prop` are not actual types, but their "codes" which need to be "decoded" to actualy types. QT-All says that `all` is decoded as `Π`. This is a bit like Tarski-style universes, if you're familiar with those.

Comment: Martin Hoffman's thesis: 
and Syntax and Semantics of Dependent
Types https://www.tcs.ifi.lmu.de/mitarbeiter/martin-hofmann/pdfs/syntaxandsemanticsof-dependenttypes.pdf might provide some more context and examples

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is false that the only well-typed occurrence of `Prf` has to be of the form `Prf(all ...)`. For example, in the context with a variable `p : Prop` we can form the type `Prf(p)` which is not of the stated form. Another possibility is that we have a `Prf(t)` for some closed term `t : Prop` which is not of the form `all ...` but it *normalizes* to it.

The purpose of `Prf` is to decode, or coerce, the elements of `Prop` to types. That is, the elements of `Prop` are *not* actual types, so if we want to use them as if they were types, they first have to be coerced to types, which is what `Prf` does. The rule `QT-All` states that `all` decodes to `Π`.

To put it differently, `Prop` is a [Tarski universe](https://ncatlab.org/homotopytypetheory/show/universe#Tarski) and `Prf` is the type family that decodes its elements as types.